Tanstack Query + Shadcn - How to show a toast msg if a new row is added to my datatable
I'm fetching and polling an external Api with Tanstack Query and showing all the data in a datatable (shadcn). I want to show a toast msg on my page every case if a fetch is successful and a new item appeared in the data. (data length is increased). I'm new with Tanstack, any idea would be appreciated!
  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data: listingsData,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['listingsData'],
    queryFn: () =>
      fetch(`${process.env.baseUrl}/test`).then((res) =>
        res.json()
      ),
    refetchInterval: 2000,
    retry: 5,
  });


First we need to save the latest items.
const previousItemsIds = useRef([]);

Then let's compare the new data with previous data
const previousItemsIds = useRef([]);

const {
  isLoading,
  error,
  data: listingsData,
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['listingsData'],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const items = await fetch(`${process.env.baseUrl}/test`).then((res) =>
      res.json()
    );

    if (itemsIds.length === 0) {
      // this is the first time data is fetched. let's save the data for later
      previousItemsIds.current = items;
    } else {
      const newItemsIds = data.map(item => item.id) // we need any unique value. mostly it's `id`

      // if there is new items:
      const isNewItem = newItemsIds.some(id => previousItemsIds.current.includes(id) === false);

      if (isNewItem) {
        toast("There is a new item")
        // let's save the latest changed items
        previousItemsIds.current = newItemsIds
      }
    }
   
  },
  refetchInterval: 2000,
  retry: 5,
});


That's probably the better solution to ensure that there are elements that are actually new but in my opinion newItemsIds.some affects performance too much when it comes to a really big dataset

How many items in your expectation?

If you care about performance, so 2seconds refreshInterval is not performant. and Array.some is performant enouph if your data is not millions (i'm sure it's not). If you wan't to level up the performance and you have a field for example createdAt or id is a serial number. you can check only items after the lastCreatedAt or greeter than the lastId.

Thank you guys, I really appreciate it! Ahmed, one question: what is 'itemsIds'?

Array of ids of items

Remember your previous data length and then compare the current length to the old one. If it is higher then fire your toast.
const [previousLength, setPreviousLength] = useState<number | undefiend>(undefined);

// ... your useQuery hook

useEffect(() => {
  if (previousData !== undefined && listingsData.length > previousLength) {
    // FIRE YOUR TOAST
  }
  setPreviousLength(listingsData.length)
}, [listingsData.length, previousLength]);


This is one of the (You Might Not Need an Effect)
